# Phonegap inAppBrowser , target _self doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova, webview, inappbrowser

As title says, i'm trying to make target _self for inAppBrowser plugin to open an external link inside the phonegap webview. But currently it opens in inAppBrowser instead.

i'm using this config:

```
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />

<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature> 

<access origin="*" />
```

the function i'm using is the following:

```
function ready() {
            $.ajax({url: "http://mydomain",
                type: "HEAD",
                timeout: 1000,
                statusCode: {
                    200: function (response) {
                        cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://mydomain','_self');
                    },
                    400: function (response) {
                        $("#loading").html("No Connection");
                    },
                    0: function (response) {
                        $("#loading").html("No Connection");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", ready, false);
```

and currently it's my behaviour:

_self -> inAppBrowser ( should open in webview instead )

_blank -> inAppBrowser

_system -> Android default browser

My objective is to create a static content ( index.html stored in apk ) that is a fallback page in case of no connection exists with the site ( no device network for example ), so i cannot use  if someone would suggest it.

Answer (score -3):

In JavaScript use can use window.open("http://google.com","_self");

Comment: i've already tried it, it's the same behaviour of cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://mydomain','_self');

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?